# PHP CSV Generation - Polish charater turned to their html entities

Tags: php, csv, polish

When i try to insert polish character in Csv file .The polish character automatically turned to their respective htmlentities

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');   
header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=reports.csv');

echo ('åĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻąćęłńóśźż');

?>
Output: å&#260;&#262;&#280;&#321;&#323;Ó&#346;&#377;&#379;&#261;&#263;&#281;&#322;&#324;ó&#347;&#378;&#380;
```

I need polish character to be displayed there.

Can anyone help me in order to solve this?

Thank you

Comment: Try with `echo("")` instead of `echo('')`

Comment: Even double quotes is not working dude....

Comment: Do one thing: Try this: `header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8');`

Comment: Your code works fine: Output [in view with Editor] is åĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻąćęłńóśźż: How did you open the output?

Comment: I used your header dude but it is not working too....

Comment: @donald I view in microsoft excel.Since the csv file will open in MS Excel only..

Comment: I think the problem is in your Excel(Settings) ... In MS Excel 2007 the output just works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=reports.csv');

$data = 'åĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻąćęłńóśźż';

$csv_output = '="'.$data.'"'.chr(9).chr(13);

$csv_output = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($csv_output, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');

echo $csv_output;

?>
```

Also do not forget to **save your php file as UTF-8 without BOM** ...

`chr(9)` seprates fields and `chr(13)` separates rows ...

Comment: ="å&#260;&#262;&#280;&#321;&#323;Ó&#346;&#377;&#379;&#261;&#263;&#281;&#322;&#324;ó&#347;&#378;&#380;"

Comment: OK, I updated the answer again, it should work now 100% ... Test the new code again ...

Comment: Are you sure that you have added my code update? `$csv_output = chr(255).chr(254).mb_convert_encoding($csv_output, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');` should be in your code, here is a file I created exactly with same code and it is working for me in my Excel 2010: http://encodable.com/uploaddemo/files/reports.csv

Comment: Your php file should be UTF-8 without BOM, is it? (There are two UTF-8 files, one is with BOM, one is without BOM, a file with BOM can cause unwanted problems since it outputs something before your php code to browser)

Comment: Hey thats really Great...It is working Awesome..Thanks for the precious time that you have spend for this..Thank you very much..GBU